# Unable to update the Subview in a Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` in which I have two `UIViews` . I want to change the BackgroundColor radius and some more properties of `UIViews`.

But I am unable to do so.

Here is my setUp.

Step 1:

```
Create A Custom Cell with XIB.
```

Step 2: Entered the `Cell Identifer` name in `XIB` for `CustomCell`.

Step 3: Instantiated `NIB` in `viewDidLoad`

```
 UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil];
 [[self mTableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
```

Step 4: Cell For Row At Index Method:

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    // Create an instance of ItemCell
   CustomCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

   [cell updateCellView];

   return cell;
}
```

Step 5: Checked Twice the Outlet Connections all are Fine.

Step 6: Custom Cell Class:

```
    #import "TransportCell.h"

    @implementation TransportCell

    - (void)awakeFromNib {
         // Initialization code

      }

    - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
       [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

        // Configure the view for the selected state
     }


    - (void)updateCellView
    {
     self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

   @end
```

This code has no effect on my Cell View.

I debug the code. When I logged the `backgroundView` I get `nil` when  `updateCellView` method get called:

[image]

Here is my CustomCell's Xib:

[image]

I have to change the Properties of Inner UIView.(Blue in color)

Comment: try self.backgrondColor = [UIColor redcolor]

Comment: it will change the cell background color

Comment: have you make outlet for your backgroundview or is it connected to your view?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the method in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` try this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    // Create an instance of ItemCell
   CustomCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
   return cell;
}
```

and then in your custom method

```
- (void)updateCellView
    {
     self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

     // reload the table view
     [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

Comment: bro are you seen the question , the method is present in cell class not in current view controller

Comment: How I get the reference for table view in My Custom cell

Comment: sorry i didn't check that...but you can also create a custom method in the viewcontroller and from that you can manage the views

Answer (score 0):

you need to add [ tableview reloadData ] 
 in method update cell view

Comment: updateCellView method is in customClass. how can I pass reference to that custom cell

Answer (score 0):

Ideally all the info needed to render the cell should come from either the data source or other events. For example, if you are changing the border-color it should mean that either some entity (say user) has performed an event or something has changed in the data-source like a value passed its threshold.

The change in data-source or those events should either trigger refreshing the whole table:

```
-(void) reloadData
```

or some cells:

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

Only then the cells will get updated.

Comment: I want to change these properties before the cells appear to user. when User get my cell first time I want them to appear rounded

Comment: reload functions are used to refresh the table dynamically. Do you want to update your cells dynamically based on events or update them only the first time they are rendered?

Answer (score 0):

try this method in TransportCell, it's swift code make same for objective c

```
override func layoutSubviews() 
{
 self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are changing the `self.backgroundview.backgroundColor`

Default it is `nil` for cells in `UITableViewStylePlain`, and non-nil for `UITableViewStyleGrouped`.

The 'backgroundView' will be added as a subview behind all other views.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, nullable) UIView *backgroundView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Hope this helps!